# Height of ListView in dialog in android not set as per the number of items in ListView; results in blank space when there are less number of options

Tags: android, listview, dialog, popup, height

Result is appropriate when there are enough options; [image-> result is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysk8I.png), But when there are less options in listview then there will be empty space; which I don't want to be there.[image-> not ok result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACJkh.png)

**I want to set the height like, when there are less options, there should not be any blank space bw. cancel button and list view.**

Code for `list_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_regular"
        android:text="Please select country"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialogList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"></ListView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

code for `list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.rohan.myvoice.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/option_select_color"
    android:textSize="16sp" />


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:background="@color/line_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't use the other views like fragment and such, as then there will be lot of changes in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You set the **layout_weight to 10 which is not required** here for list view **we just want to use wrap_content in layout_heigh**t:-

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialogList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"></ListView>
```

Please check by Trying Recycler view instead of List View using my code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Please select country"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dialogList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if i not provide weight 10 then , cancel button is going under list view.!

Comment: you can try by setting particular width height of button

Comment: please try changed answer, if helpful please tell me